# ASP-No out put for Large number of records

Tags: asp-classic

I have an ASP page which will query records from a DB Table and do some processing and then Render an HTML table in the browser.My table has more than 16000 rows in it. When i am running the prigram with select top 2500 StudId,StudName from StudentsTbl, It is working fine.But when i am Using select  "StudId,StudName from StudentsTbl",It is not showing any out put. I am using Response.flush() after every 50 records in the while loop.Can any one tell me how to solve this ? Thanks in advance

---

Actaully I would create an Excel file from this ASP page by adding Response..ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel" Thats y i need to generate the all data one time

Comment: Are you using application/vnd.ms-excel now? Does that still fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem, I'm betting that you're using IE as your test browser. The Response.Flush() *is* outputting HTML, but it will not display right away because IE doesn't know how to render a table incrementally. Instead, IE waits for the entire table to output before it draws it to the browser window. Your script isn't the problem, IE is.

With that being said, I want to point out that your design is fundamentally flawed. Think about your script from a usability perspective: there is no sane reason why you need to output 16000 rows of data all at once. [Page your recordset in SQL](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/30/2652.aspx), or limit the recordset to first 1000 rows using a TOP clause.

Comment: I agree the most likely explanation is that its taking a long time to download the complete table before IE renders the content.  Paging or limiting recordset isn't the answer as the question itself indicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting it as a table to the browser - I bet you get a "Script Timed Out" error.

Best bet would be to up the timeout interval. You can do that with a bit of code at the start of the script or you can do that as a global server setting. I would recommend the former.

Answer (score 0):

Server.ScriptTimeout = 3939393

put it at the top of your page (I just choose a random high number). I assume you are getting a timeout from IIS. Default is 90 seconds.

Take away your response.flush, it only makes it slower as the server has to output every X ms to the client. Buffer the entire page instead (should be set as default in IIS for better performance).

If it still fails, what is the error? Maybe your databas is slow.